# How to read parameters from fullfilment request dialogflow using webhook?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How can I read paramters from fullfilment request, as an example my intent from dialogflow has a parameter called money_value which has a type of @sys.number. how to use it inside webhook, I did something like

```
Double money = (Double) request.getParameter("money_value")
```

also how to get parameter from a context? Thank you

Comment: It is a little difficult to answer your question without more information. We don't know, for example, what language you're using, or if you're using a library inside the webhook to parse the request. The more code and information you can provide, the better our chances are of helping you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

When you define a parameter in Dialogflow you can access to it from your code in the fulfillment request.

When the intent is detected a request is created to your webhook and you can access to that information in the code side, for example:

```
const caseLevel = agent.parameters.caseLevel;
const priority = agent.parameters.priority;
```

[image]